# the <ul> isn't collapsing , only extending

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

The problem is that when I press on `<a>Categories</a>` the `<ul>` is extending
but when I press again does nothing

In my CSS file is have set `display:none;`

I have this in my php/html page

```
<html>
<head>
...
<script src="javascript/collapse.js"></script>
...
</head>

<body>...<ul>
   <a href="#" onclick="collapse('id1')">Categories</a>
   <ul id="id1">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Business</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="home.php">Entertainment</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="home.php">Social Media</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="home.php">Others</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>...</html>
```

And this in my collapse.js file

```
function collapse(id){
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display="block")
        e.style.display="none";
    if(e.style.display="none")
        e.style.display="block";
};
```

I need to use only html,css and javascript , no others frameworks or libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should use triple equals for comparisions in javascript. Second, you should use an `else if` statement, otherwise the second `if` will always negate the first one:

```
if(e.style.display === "block"){
  e.style.display="none";
} else if (e.style.display === "none") {
  e.style.display="block";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the code in the question above is pasted properly then the problem is in the **=**

The `e.style.display="block"` line assigns a value **(=)**, it's not checking for equality **(==)**

```
function collapse(id){
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display=="block")
        e.style.display="none";
    else
        e.style.display="block";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing the style in your ifs. You are setting it. The value of that expression the value you set, i.e. a non-empty string, which is a true value in JavaScript. Hence the first branch is always executed.

You need to change the assignments to comparisons with the comparison operator (==), better yet in JavaScriot the strict version (===), as correctly pointed out by @mpadittech.

You also need an else so the second branch isn't executed after a value change in the first.

```
function collapse(id){
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.display==="block")
    e.style.display="none";
else if(e.style.display==="none")
    e.style.display="block";
};
```